# Keep unique index (or id) in pandas when appending

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new row in pandas DataFrame. But also, I want to have another DataFrame that references the first one.
For example, I have a table with news, each row is a unique news, e.g.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: ['company1 is bankrupt'],
                        1: ['company2 and company3 are going to merge. company1 is good'],
                        2: ['company3 is going to create a new product. CEO of company3 says it will be a good product']}, orient='index', columns=['text'])
```

I also want to keep information on what companies are in each news and how many times each one appears in the text. I want to create a new dataframe such as:

```
index company  freq    
news1 company1 2  
news1 company2 1   
news2 company3 3
```

...
But to do this, I need to have stable id of a news, but if I append, I need to reindex. and if I deleted a news in the middle, then reindex, id will be changed, so appending a new row can change my id, so I can't reference this id. What should I do? Maybe I should create a dataframe (or dictionary) in dataframe to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply, as you said, create an ID for the news? It doesn't need to be in the index. Simply do:

```
df['news_id'] = [i for i in range(len(df))]
```

This will attach an ID (duplicate to your index, probably) to each news. Now you can just reference `news_id` in your appended rows, without worrying about the index.

EDIT: If you are regularly updating the database, you can simply use a more complex ID creator. Something like:

```
import random
characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789'
used_ids = []
def pick_id():
    global used_ids #this allows us to use and modify the used_ids list in the function
    ID = ''.join([random.choice(characters) for i in range(16)]) #arbitrary length of 16 for IDs
    while ID in used_ids: #this simply repeats the generation of IDs if the ID is already in used_ids
        ID = ''.join([random.choice(characters) for i in range(16)])
    used_ids.append(ID) #now add the used ID to used_ids
    return ID
```

Now you can simply do:

```
df['news_id'] = [pick_id() for i in range(len(df))]
```

This requires that you keep track of news_id but it's not so bad: whenever you run this program you can read your new dataframe like thus:

```
used_ids = list(set(list(new_dataframe['news_id'])))
```

That will give you all unique IDs already taken.

Comment: The problem is I constantly update the dataframe, so id of a news will change each time I remove a news that is not in the end